# Calling a method with non-standard-class argument in Freemarker template

Tags: java, templates, enums, freemarker

There are a lot of questions asking how to call a non-bean method on a value set in the root map. How do I do this when the parameter I am passing-in is not of a standard type (e.g., when it's an enum (or any other class for that matter) I have defined)?

For example, I can trivially do the following in my Freemarker template:

```
<p>${product.name}</p>
<p>${product.normalizedDescription()}</p>
```

but what about when the method I am calling takes a `Currency enum` I have defined in my Java code?

```
<p>${product.getPriceAsString(Currency.USD)}</p>
```

How does the template know the `Currency enum` and where to find its definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naive solution is putting the value of `Currency.USD` (the Java enum value itself) into the data-model, say, with name `"USD"`, and then you can write `${product.getPriceAsString(USD)}`.

Of course it can be a problem to put all the enum values into the data-model like that. So you can put `((BeansWrapper) cfg.getObjectWrapper()).getEnumModels().get(Currency.class.getName())` into the data-model with name `"Currency"`, and then `${product.getPriceAsString(Currency.USD)}` should work.

You can go one more step further and put `((BeansWrapper) cfg.getObjectWrapper()).getEnumModels()` with name `enums` into the data-model and then the template could do things like `<#assign Currency = enums['com.example.Currency']>`, but that starts to be a bit too anti-MVC.

Also note that instead of putting these into the data-model, you can put these values into the `Configuration` as shared variables.